# My LED display fails with MSGEQ7 output stuck

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, led-strip

I have an Arduino setup with a pro-mini, a MSGEQ7, and a auto-gain mic. Even if I remove the audio input to the MSGEQ7 remains the same in the 890s (out of 1024). It's the same on each of two new MSGEQ7. I've checked the schematics, https://www.instructables.com/Music-Sync-Flashing-LEDs-Arduino-MSGEQ7/, multiple times and everything seems in order including components.

I'm using the `#include <MD_MSGEQ7.h>`, but I've tried it without.

Any ideas?

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include <MD_MSGEQ7.h>

int LEDPIN = 12;
int MODEPIN = 10;

int mode = 0;
int lastState = LOW;

int NUMPIXELS = 50;

int DATA_PIN = 1; // read from multiplexer using Analog Pin 1, MSGEQ7 pin 3
int STROBE_PIN = 2; // MSGEQ7 pin 4
int RESET_PIN = 3; // MSGEQ7 pin 7

int spectrumValue[7];

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, LEDPIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
MD_MSGEQ7 MSGEQ7(RESET_PIN, STROBE_PIN, DATA_PIN);

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(MODEPIN, INPUT);
  pixels.begin();
  MSGEQ7.begin();
}

void loop() {
  int currentState = digitalRead(MODEPIN);

  if (currentState == LOW && lastState == HIGH) {
    mode++;
    if (mode > 2) {
      mode = 0;
    }
  }
  lastState = currentState;
  
  MSGEQ7.read();

  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    Serial.println(MSGEQ7.get(i));
  }
  if (mode == 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMPIXELS - 1; i++) {
      pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(30, 60, 60)); // RGB
    }
  } else if (mode == 1) {/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int height = (NUMPIXELS - 1) * MSGEQ7.get(1) / 1024;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMPIXELS - 1; i++) {
      if (i < height) {
        pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(60, 60, 0)); // RGB
      } else {
        pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0, 0, 0)); // RGB
      }
    }
  } else if (mode == 2) { /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    pixels.setPixelColor(0, pixels.Color(120 * MSGEQ7.get(5) / 1024, 0, 0)); // RGB
  }
  pixels.show();
}
```

Comment: Not much to go on here. Where's your code? Are you saying you followed the schematic in that article exactly, including components? What does "...I remove the mic the output..." mean?

Comment: Edited. Thank you.